# How can I speed up the first-time loading of a Windows device driver for an USB device?

Tags: windows-xp, driver, device-driver, drivers, driver-signing

We have some boxes running Windows XP for an automated production process. I (not me personally but a robot) connect new USB devices to these boxes. There is a device driver for this device type and it's loaded after connecting a device and running like a charm.

But ... it takes about 8 to 10 seconds after pluging in a ***new*** device until it is accessible. When I connect an ***already previously seen*** device again it only takes 3 seconds. The driver has a catalog file. It's not signed by Microsoft WHQL but uses a test certificate we have installed on the machines.

There is only one inf/pnf file to be considered and so I wonder why it takes so long to detect a new device, create the information in the registry and load the driver. 
Time is money and so I need to speed up the process.

Any hints for me? Especially does somebody *know* that WHQL-certified drivers are recognized more quickly by Windows / device manager?

Comment: Yes, this is fairly normal performance. Why are you constantly plugging in new devices?

Comment: The only way I found, was to get the driver whql'ed, but I am open for better suggestions.

Comment: @Cody Gray: It's part of a production process: I write some data to every device, read serial number etc, do QA tests. The performance is okay, but there are other devices (with a WHQL certified driver), which are available after 2 seconds. And so the automation guy says we should keep up with it.

Comment: So the solution seems obvious: get your driver WHQL certified. Seems like a good idea for a hardware vendor anyway...

Comment: @Christopher: Do you know a WHQL certified driver is loaded more quickly than a driver which is signed using a self-signed certificate? Or do you guess?

Comment: @Cody Gray: We don't need a device driver after production, actually.

Comment: You just *said* that a WHQL certified driver loaded faster. This question makes no sense.

Comment: @Cody Gray: You're right. Sorry for the misunderstanding. What I meant in my comment was that we have another (similar) device type for which a WHQL certified driver exists. And we observe that Windows displays these devices after about 2 or 3 seconds. Now we are wondering what the reason is and are guessing what the reason is.

Comment: Maybe your questions should be phrased as "Can someone *confirm* my suspicion that WHQL certified drivers are installed faster than non-certified ones?"

Comment: @ur Yes, I know that self signed drivers do not load as quickly as whql'ed drivers. (NB: You already should selfsign your drivers, just to get x64 to work). Nevertheless, when there is a better solution to speed up the process, I am inclined to try.

Comment: Take a look at the setupapi.log and compare the sequences for the WHQL and the non-WHQL driver. On an unrelated note, how do you even install non-WHQL drivers automatically? You should only be able to install them manually (by going through a wizard), not through what setupapi calls "server install".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These devices have unique serial numbers, correct? That's part of what Windows uses to create the per-instance data necessary to track whether it's seen this device before. In the case where you plug in a device that's already seen before, Windows will pick up the old instance data and load the appropriate driver. If you plug in a device that Windows has never seen before (e.g. same VID/PID but different serial number), it needs to go through the process of creating registry entries, parsing the INFs to find the correct driver, etc.

Are you sure those devices that show up quickly with WHQL'd drivers have never been attached to the system before? Also, are these systems configured to connect to Windows Update to look for drivers when a new device is attached? It's definitely true that Windows will prefer a WHQL'd driver over an unsigned (or self signed) package, so it's possible that Windows is trying hard to find something else before defaulting to your self signed driver.

-scott

Comment: Yes, unique serial numbers. I'm quite sure that the devices with the WHQL'd driver show up faster, but I didn't test it on my own...  Currently I can't answer your question about Windows Update. Thank you for your answer, I will investigate on this.